# Batch File of Changing macro-enabled file to excel file with its actual instance?

Tags: excel, batch-file

**Batch File:**Code

@echo off
copy /Y "D:\ExcelTest\temp*.*" "D:\ExcelTest\copied*.xls"

**Action:**The above code will create a macro enabled file to excel format file from source location to destination successfully,

**Problem:**The originality of that excel extension won't treat this as Excel File,whenever we try to open a file it pops up undefined format and asks Yes or No or Cancel,

**Expectation:**Whenever we wants to open a excel file it should open directly without any pop up and it should show as excel file

When I rename the file, I am changing the extension from .xlsm to .xls.  When I try to launch this, Excel pops a dialog saying "The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the file extension..."

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Could you clarify a little?  The code you have there won't do what you think it will, for starters.  If you have (say) tempfoo.txt and you try to use that line, it will create copiedo.xls (that is, the string 'copied' will overwrite the first 6 characters of 'tempfoo').

I suspect that's not the biggest problem, though.  We'll need more information about the contents of the files too.

Comment: Mark,source location(folder) having the Macro file called 30-3-12 TO 10-6-12.xlsm, after running batch file it will copies the name of the file as it is with the extension xls to the destination location (folder) (Ex:) 30-3-12 TO 10-6-12.xls,my actual query is while double click on the 30-3-12 TO 10-6-12.xls file it is not opening as excel file,instead of that it asking pop up message such as

Comment: "The file you are trying to open, '30-3-12 TO 10-6-12.xls', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?" Yes /No / Help(Buttons)

Comment: i wanna avoid such situation it should be as excel so i need some more batch code to save as excel format file

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.  You have changed the file extension from .xlsm (a macro-enabled workbook) to .xls (a regular workbook, of an older version of Excel).

Solution: Don't change the extension in the first place and Excel should open the files just fine.

```
copy /y D:\ExcelTest\*.xlsm D:\ExcelTest\copied*.xlsm
```